# How to bind C-h to delete-backward-char when doing isearch?

Tags: key-bindings, isearch, deletion

I use C-h as an alias for `delete-backward-char` everywhere.

But when I do isearch it exits the search instead of deleting the character before the cursor.

I tried binding C-h in isearch maps, but that didn't work:

```
(define-key minibuffer-local-isearch-map (kbd "C-h") 'delete-backward-char)
(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "C-h") 'delete-backward-char)
```

Character gets deleted, but it is deleted in the buffer, not in the isearch prompt.

Is there a way to rebind C-h so it works in isearch prompt?

Comment: Isearch does not use the minibuffer, in spite of appearance (with the exception of `M-e`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in general, Isearch uses the minibuffer only for `M-e`.  So your `minibuffer-local-isearch-map` key binding is useless here.  That's the keymap used when editing after `M-e`.

Second, your `isearch-mode-map` binding means that `C-h` ends up deleting the char in the buffer you're searching, not deleting a char from the search string. The current buffer remains the buffer you're searching.

This is what you need to do. It defines a command that pops the last char off of the end of the search string.

```lisp
(defun foo ()
  "Delete last char of the search string."
  (interactive)
  (unless (equal isearch-string "") (isearch-pop-state))
  (isearch-update))

(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "C-h") 'foo)
```